# How does thermal insulation work at the molecular level?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science

I don't understand why insulation works. For example, imagine we have the same thickness of wood, fiberglass and aerogel. Each insulates to a different degree, the more rarified material, the greater the insulation. I don't understand why this is.

For example, even though there might be more air and light molecules in fiberglass than wood, when a molecule strikes those, the energy is conserved. So, for example, if a molecule of air struck versus a molecule of cellulose, the air might have less mass, but since the energy is conserved, it just means the molecule of air will end moving faster (mv = mv) than the molecule of cellulose. So, I would expect the same amount of energy to be transported in both cases.

What am I missing?

Note that the same exact question was asked on Quora and got only two answers, a hand-waving read-the-textbook answer with no information, and another which said this:

> An alternative view; Electric potential (of an atom) is the magnitude
>   of angular deflection of its atomic axis, from its natural alignment
>   with respect to axes of neighboring atoms, when in electrically
>   neutral state. Any property of atom/molecule that reduces ability of
>   neighboring atoms to influence relative deflections of their atomic
>   axes will increase insulating property of a material. For more
>   details, see: Chapter 14 of 'MATTER (Re-examined)'.

I don't really understand this "answer".

Comment: It's saying the atoms have a higher resistance to deflection from their natural alignment compared to less insulated counterparts.  It seems reasonable that a larger spacing will (on average) decrease the interaction between insulating particles (and their environment).  It also seems reasonable that some material configurations would naturally do this more than others.

Comment: Looking at the molecular level will not help your understanding. If anything, it will hinder it. You won't see phonons at the Angstrom level, or collisions between gas molecules. You won't see convection (the beast that conventional insulation tries to defeat) at the nanoscale, or even at the microscale.

Answer (score 3):

> Each insulates to a different degree, the more rarified material, the greater the insulation. I don't understand why this is.

I will try to explain this part with a very schematic example.

[image]

In the picture above, an air molecule collides with a compact wall, for example a crystal, separating two spatial areas, A and B. Treating the molecules as billiard balls, we will say that the air molecule will hit precisely one molecule of the wall and then bounce away.

The momentum delivered by the air molecule will result in a vibration of the molecule which was hit. Since the material is dense, this vibration will be immediately transmitted to the nearby molecules.

So, collision after collision, the vibration (temperature!) of the molecules of the wall will increase and increase, until a state of equilibrium is reached. I speak of equilibrium because also the molecules of the wall will transfer momentum to the surrounding air molecules!

So if side A was initially hotter than side B, side B will get hot in no time because of the energy transferred by the vibration of the molecules of the wall.

At equilibrium, for the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem), the average kinetic energy of *every* molecule in the system (side A, side B and wall) will be

$$\langle \epsilon \rangle = \frac f 2 k_B T$$

where $f$ is the number of degrees of freedom of the molecule ($3$ for a gas particle, $6$ for a particle in a perfect 3D crystal) and $T$ is the equilibrium temperature.

Let's now consider the case depicted below:

[image]

The compact wall has now been replaced by two very thin layers containing some gas. You can see that in this case, when an air molecule hits the wall, the vibration is again immediately transmitted to the nearby molecules in the wall, but only *rarely* to the gas molecules contained in it.

You can then see that this time it will take much longer to get all the gas molecules contained in the wall to receive the kinetic energy and transfer it to the molecules contained in side B.

This is why solid materials have an [higher thermal conductivity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/thrcn.html) than gases (and liquids): because when the molecules are far apart from each other it is difficult to transfer energy.

Moreover, ordered materials (crystals) have an higher thermal conductivity than disordered materials (such as glasses), because in the former the vibration can be transferred through well defined directions, i.e. the atoms can vibrate in a synchronous way along preferred directions, while in the latter this is not possible.

Indeed, glass has a terrible thermal conductivity, about 0.8 W/m K. Water and air are even worse, with thermal conductivities of respectively 0.6 and 0.024 W/m K.

Silver, copper and gold are quite amazing thermal conductors, with conductivities of respectively 406, 385 and 314 W/ m K.

But the real hero is diamond, with an astonishing 1000 W/m K: its secret is in its perfect tetrahedral network structure of strong covalent bonds, equals in every direction, which allow it to transfer vibration efficiently from one atom to the other.

Comment: Yeah I agree with your explanation i am also searching for this kind of explanation for this question . But according to your explanation i am having a question that if we somehow able to increase the amount of air present between the two layers of the insulator( as per your second case in the explanation ) will the conductivity of the material increase?

Comment: @RifatSafin That's correct. Just think about it: vacuum is the best insulator after all...

Comment: @ valerio....Hmm ok , thank you